# How to share a vagrant machine with https

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile, vagrant-share

I have a working vagrant VM I want to [Share](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/). In my Vagrantfile I have:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.1.15"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 443
```

in the virtual host I have

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
ServerAlias *.vagrantshare.com
....
</Virtualhost>
```

not sure about the first line but it was there already

I share the machine with

```
vagrant share --https 443
```

this is the output:

```
==> default: Detecting network information for machine...
default: Local machine address: 127.0.0.1
default:  
default: Note: With the local address (127.0.0.1), Vagrant Share can only
default: share any ports you have forwarded. Assign an IP or address to your
default: machine to expose all TCP ports. Consult the documentation
default: for your provider ('virtualbox') for more information.
default:  
default: Local HTTP port: 8080
default: Local HTTPS port: 443
default: Port: 2222
default: Port: 443
default: Port: 8080
==> default: Checking authentication and authorization...
==> default: Creating Vagrant Share session...
default: Share will be at: towering-badger-9312
==> default: Your Vagrant Share is running! Name: towering-badger-9312
==> default: URL: http://towering-badger-9312.vagrantshare.com
==> default:  
==> default: You're sharing your Vagrant machine in "restricted" mode. This
==> default: means that only the ports listed above will be accessible by
==> default: other users (either via the web URL or using `vagrant connect`).
```

I can see it in vagrant cloud but I got an error while trying to access it via https:

```
towering-badger-9312.vagrantshare.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

not any other useful message in the console, any idea how to debug this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace this line

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 443
```

by i.e.:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
```

First, because `forwarded_port` is for port accessing from the `host` and second, you will not be able to bind to port 443 on host anyway, unless Vagrant is run as root because of binding to ports < 1023 require root privileges. This is also documented in Vagrant docs [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/networking/forwarded_ports#options-reference).

Also

```bash
vagrant share --https 443
```

is redundant ([docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/http.html)):

> HTTPS (SSL)
>
> Vagrant Share can also expose an SSL port that can be accessed over
> SSL. For example, instead of accessing http://foo.vagrantshare.com, it
> could be accessed at https://foo.vagrantshare.com.
>
> vagrant share by default looks for any SSL traffic on port 443 in your
> development environment. If it cannot find any, then SSL is disabled
> by default.

so

```bash
vagrant share
```

should suffice (assuming there's no other issue).

Comment: I tried this but when sharing I get "default: Local HTTPS port: disabled". on my 443 guest there is apache and from my host it works. any other idea? thanks.

Comment: now when sharing I get 


default: Local HTTP port: 8080
    
default: Local HTTPS port: 8443

http works but https now says error 400

Comment: Clarifying @Marcin's statement *"you should not be able to bind to port 443 on host"* - this is a Linux restriction for ports < 1024, see re. `hosts` in the Vagrant [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/networking/forwarded_ports#options-reference) for forwarded ports.

Comment: Good point. Updated the answer. Thanks